# Python Array to multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have a problem to combining array to multidimensional array.

My Array

```
['Fiat', 'black', 'new', 'BMW', 'white', 'new']
```

The result should look like this

```
[['Fiat'], ['black'], ['new'], ['BMW'], ['white'], ['new']]
```

What do I have to do to achieve this result?

I am newbie. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try that:

```
a = ['Fiat', 'black', 'new', 'BMW', 'white', 'new']
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append([i])
print(b) # u will see result..
```

Answer (score 6):

That simplest way is probably to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = ['Fiat', 'black', 'new', 'BMW', 'white', 'new']
>>> [[x] for x in l]
[['Fiat'], ['black'], ['new'], ['BMW'], ['white'], ['new']]
```